# Restart and Restarting tag synonym request

Tags: support, stack-overflow, synonym-request

[restart](/questions/tagged/restart) : 392 questions

and

[restarting](/questions/tagged/restarting) : 19 questions

That is all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Completed: [restarting](/questions/tagged/restarting) --> [restart](/questions/tagged/restart), and merged.